# How to get rid of total row and total column in rpivot table

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyjs

This is just an example code. I want to remove last row and last column with name "Total" in pivot table. Your help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("ramnathv/htmlwidgets") 
install_github("smartinsightsfromdata/rpivotTable")
## Load rpivotTable
library(rpivotTable)
data(mtcars)
## One line to create pivot table
rpivotTable(mtcars, rows="gear", col="cyl", aggregatorName="Average", 
            vals="mpg", rendererName="Treemap")
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try:

```
data <-rpivotTable(mtcars, rows="gear", col="cyl", aggregatorName="Average", 
            vals="mpg", rendererName="Treemap")
```

To drop last row:

```
data <- data[-nrow(data), ]
```

To drop last column/specific column name:

```
## drop column of specific name
drop <- "Total"
data[, !(names(data) %in% drop)]
## drop last column
data[, -ncol(data)]
```

Drop both at once:

```
data[-nrow(data), !(names(data) %in% drop)]
```

or

```
data[-nrow(data), -ncol(data)]
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much.